# play store not working

Tags: huawei, huawei-honor-6

I am unable to download anything from play store..and I am also not able to access any service of google like gmail, picasa google+ . I have already reset my phone after half hour till reset my phone works properly bt further it starts behaving the same as it was before reset

Comment: Show us the error (screenshots(s))? Is the problem only with Google owned apps or with any app in your device?

Answer (score -1):

You root ?? Reinstall services google play, perhaps it hurts you.
With a browser sees root / data / app / and reinstalls com.google.android.gms.apk
If you are not root then geting rooty if you want your android root flashes. Of course you'll have to find your rom.

Comment: No I havn't root it yet, n I dnt want to either any other solution.

Comment: How does that help in resolving the issue?

Comment: @Firelord experience.